# Python multi line comments inside dict() or function parameter

Tags: python, comments

I have tried with docstring,

```
def foo("""No params"""):
    # I have tried to comment in params. If I try Hash(#) then, it goes to the whole line
    File "<stdin>", line 1


def foo("""asdadadasd"""):
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Some other programming languages, Like JavaScript, it's working.
For Example,

```
function foo(/*no params*/) {
    console.log("Success");
}
```

#### Is there any way to it in Python?

Comment: Actually, I just need to comment out some sections. So I don't wanna allocate memory for this string. And it doesn't make sense to comment. It look like a function parameter. Thanks for comment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A docstring is a type of string literal; Python doesn’t have multi-line comments, as you’d normally be able to put a `#` before every line. In this case, you need a comment that doesn’t even span a line, though, which isn’t possible. What *is* possible is breaking the signature across multiple lines:

```
def foo(
    # no params
):
    ...
```

Or making use of a normal function docstring:

```
def foo():
    """
    ...

    Takes no parameters.
    """
```

Still, I wouldn’t add a comment like “no params” to begin with; it’s not really useful.

Comment: Wow!! Nice to see that. So I can need to use hash(#) everywhere. Like, 
`a = {
# comment 1
# comment 2
'name': 'foo bar'
}`